# Getting "this" for ontouchmove event?

Tags: jquery, ipad, mobile, touch

I'm currently trying to build out a mobile web app in HTML5, and was wondering if somebody could point me in the right direction.

I'd like to emulate the A-Z section index feature in the iphone/ipad using javascript. Here is a sencha example you can view on webkit: http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/oreilly/ **(click on "speakers")**

Here is the function I have so far:

```
            $(".jumplistitem").bind("touchmove", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            letter = $(this).text().toLowerCase();
            scrolltarget = ".x-group-" + letter;
            merchantScroll.scrollToElement(scrolltarget, 0);
        });
```

The function fires fine on a simple click or touch event, but I need that "dragging" behavior you see on the example. So the user just drags his/her finger up and down the a-z list, and the function fires accordingly. Right now, it only fires one time.

Interestingly enough, it works flawlessly with a mouse using the hover event. I need to just emulate that.

I think the problem is with the "this" element, but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I found a solution..

I replaced "this" with:

    document.elementFromPoint(touch.pageX, touch.pageY)

Works great now.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer, then mark it as such.

Comment: I wish I could.. not enough reputation points on stack to do that.

Answer (score 3):

jQuery's event object contains a reference to the object that initiated the event.  In your example, that would be 'e.target'.

```
letter = e.target.text().toLowerCase();
```